# Методы сортировки смешанных данных (текст + числа)

Tags: база-данных, сортировка, алгоритм

Какие есть способы сортировки данных типа:

1. Профессиональное училище № 21
2. Профессиональное училище № 30
3. Профессиональное училище № 120

или:

1. pgAdmin v1.8.4
2. pgAdmin v1.10.5
3. pgAdmin v1.12.3

Есть ли возможность сделать это на уровне БД?

Вопрос касается не только приведенных примеров, но вообще любых возможных вкраплений в текстовые поля чисел.

Comment: Кроме добавления к таблице числового поля и триггера (хранимой процедуры на PL/SQL), который будет  заполнять это поле при вставке/обновлении числом из названия ничего в голову не приходит.

Comment: Об этом я тоже думал. Но представим себе ситуацию, когда в таблице появятся записи типа "Школа № 120" и "Училище № 120". Что-то мне подсказывает, что результат будет не айс. Конечно, имеет смысл разделить текстовое поле на два - текст + число. Но, опять же, всплывают наименования типа "Профессиональное училище № 43 Санкт-Петербурга имени Героя Советского Союза В.Я.Петрова", где число - внутри. Прибавим сюда вероятность двух и более чисел, разделенных текстом (см. версии pgAdmin выше).

Comment: Наверное осмысленный порядок сорировки это *название, номер*. Процедура "вытаскивания" номера из названия д.б. достаточно "интеллектуальна".

Answer (score 3):

имхо у вас проблема не с сортировкой данных а с проэктированием СУБД. значения то неатомарные, - посему должна иметь место оптимизация и разбиение данных на 2 поля: имя + номер или продукт + версия

если вы не слышали ничего про реляционные СУБД (втч. про нормальные формы) есть и для вас пару вариантов:

1. для всех полей которые являются комплексными нужно добавить по одному numeric полю в таблицу. и на вставку/обновление повесить триггер который будет для каждого такого поля заполнять соответствующие им поля <field>_order. которые и будут использоватся для сортировки. или же сами можете заполнять при вставке. (имеет смысл хранить эти данные в отдельной таблице)
2. можно добавить функцию которая будет подсчитывать order для сортировки на лету. выглядеть это будет как-то так:

1)    `select x.afield from xtable x order by get_order (x.afield)`
или
2)    `select x.afield from xtable x order by get_order ('xtable', 'xfield', x.afield)`

настройки для функции get_order могут хранится в какой-то отдельной таблице. в первом примере вам придется автоматически определять шаблон который использовать для определения порядка следования записи, в другом примере вы сможете с помощью if elseif... использовать алгоритм в зависимости от входных данных.

первый вариант более предпочтительный с точки зрения performance. а правильный, - оптимизация структуры СУБД

**UPDATE**:

с одной стороны полное имя учебного заведения это вроде как-бы единое значение. но это только на первый взгляд.

1. "профессиональное" (опциональный префикс, - можно игнорировать)
2. "училище" - тип учебного заведения (академия, институт, университет) может быть использовано для сортировки
3. "№ 43" - номер учебного заведения.
4. "Санкт Петербурга" - явно же город.
5. "имени" васи пупкина - даж незнаю как атрибут назвать но "имени" явно можно использовать для фильтра, - только есть ли смысл, - хз.

далее логически анализируем данные:
номер учебного заведения + его тип = уникальная комбинация (в пределах одного города) 
учебное заведение может быть расположено только в одном городе, во всех остальных будут филиалы. хотя называтся могут одинаково. т.е комбинация этих 3х полей не будет уникальной.

в результате получается таблица следующего содержимого:

```
id // уникальный id
type, // профессиональное училище / университет / академия. можно вынести в отдельную таблицу 
number, // порядковый номер. его в принцыпе может и не быть. (это надо учесть в сортировке)
dedication_id // поле которое будет хранить ссылку на id человека которому посвящено. если null - то никому не посвящено. null тоже можно учесть при сортировке
foundation_date // время когда было создано учебное заведение. имхо это важное поле.
description // или full_name/display_name - полное имя заведения, то которое вы будете отображать пользователю. и которое никогда не будет участвовать в сортировке.
location_id // ссылка на таблицу с местоположениями (ессно будет содержать город)
```

p.s. пожалуй еще лучше было бы создать отдельную таблицу отделения или филиалы. привязанную к конкретному учебному заведению. где каждый отдельный филиал имеет свой конкретный адресс. что позволит хранить данные независимые от других филиалов. напр: количество студентов/наличие кафедр/специальностей итд итп

```
таблица dedication
id, // уникальное id
prefix, //  его величество
name, // василий пупкин
```

^^ таблица нужна, т.к. одному ученому может быть посвящено больше чем 1 заведение.

p.s.s если обобщить одной фразой работу с субд: легко проэктировать = сложно работать и наоборот.

Comment: Хорошо. Тогда как оптимизировать СУБД под случаи типа **"Профессиональное училище № 43 Санкт-Петербурга имени Героя Советского Союза В.Я.Петрова"**?

Comment: @Khvorostin, это - имя собственное, а имена собственные сортируются в лексикографическом порядке.

Comment: @karmadro4, спасибо, кэп.

Comment: Тогда к чему всё это? Нерешаемое в рамках БД, смею добавить.

Comment: @karmadro4, есть подозрение, что задача все-таки решаема и именно на уровне БД.

Comment: @Khvorostin, обоснованное подозрение или не очень? Напоминаю, что для кастомизации сортировки необходимо предоставлять функцию `comparer(a, b) returns {-1, 0, 1}`.

Comment: @karmadro4, [идея пользовательских функций](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-function.html) наводит на соответствующие мысли.

Comment: @Khvorostin, посмотрите внимательно на предыдущий комментарий. Для осуществления не хватает одного параметра.